# Why is it wrong to use the gerund in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Please see the sentance below

*Composed* of heavy-textured clay *soil*, adobe *has* great elasticity when moist, but when dry is able *of holding* its shape

I'm practising spotting the error in sentences and the answer key says that "of holding* is wrong. Although it doesn't supply the right answer, I think it is probably *to hold*.

2 questions :

1 is the correct answer "to hold"?
2 why is "of holding" marked as being wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> 1 is the correct answer "to hold"?

Yes. The adjective 'able' is followed by the 'to' (infinitive) form of a verb: I am able to see you. He is able to run fast.

> 2 why is "of holding" marked as being wrong?

Because we cannot follow 'able' with 'of' and the -ing form of a verb. We could use 'capable' in that way. Adobe is capable of holding its shape.

Able to do something, capable of doing something.

[Able to (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/able)

[Capable of (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capable?q=capable%2Bof%2Bsth%252Fdoing%2Bsth)

To find what preposition to use after an adjective (that is, whether to use of, to, about, for, with, at, by, in from, etc), in a particular situation, look at the entry for the adjective in a good dictionary.

Comment: Ok many thanks! How can I learn these? What are these adjectives called?

Answer (score 0):

"Able to hold" would be right. I don't know if there's a real reason, but people don't say "i am able of doing x". However, "capable of holding its shape" would be correct.